# (Yet) Another Necromancer Question: How's it implemented?

Tags: discussion, support, badges

Yes, yes, I know, the Necromancer Badge has been beaten to death (heh) on Meta, but hear me out. I got my first Necromancer today, and naturally, I can't figure out why. So I went to CloudExchange to find out, using [this query](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/988):

```
select   
  q.id, q.title, a.score
from posts a inner join posts q
  on a.ParentId = q.id
where 
  a.OwnerUserId=12716 
  and
 a.CreationDate >= dateadd(day, 60, q.CreationDate) ​
```

Now, I didn't expect it to show the post at 5, since the database is out of sync, but none of the posts listed there come close to 5, even on SO itself (I checked), and none of my most recent answers that are over 5 appear to qualify. I went back several months; unless CloudExchange is *really* stale, I shouldn't have the Necromancer badge.

So what gives? Did I construct my query wrong? That's certainly possible, although it appears correct based on the public description of Necromancer, at least to me. I don't think the process itself is broken, but I can't be sure since I don't know the algorithm, which leads me (finally) to my question:

What's the actual algorithm for determining the Necromancer badge? I *assume* that the query is something like this (ignoring filters for existing badges):

```
select a.OwnerUserId 
from posts a inner join posts q
  on a.ParentId = q.id
where 
  a.CreationDate >= dateadd(day, 60, q.CreationDate)
  and a.Score >= 5
```

Is it actually? Or is it something else entirely?

Comment: CloudExchange is I think almost a month old. Did you try checking your reputation audit at http://stackoverflow.com/reputation ? You received both Necromancer and Nice Answer 1 hour ago, maybe you can spot the recently upvoted posts around that time and see which it is.

Comment: @ccomet: unfortunately the repuation list only shows non-wiki posts (i.e. rep earning posts). I could have received the upvote in a wiki post, which is why I went to CloudExchange.

Comment: Well, thank goodness you have the attention of persistent people. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130965/what-is-the-worst-code-youve-ever-written/466067#466067 <- Answer with 16 votes currently and posted on Jan '09, question was posted Sep '08.

Comment: @ccomet: amazing find; seriously. But... why isn't it in my query?

Comment: And why did it take so long to give you a badge? According to the timeline, it hasn't gotten a vote in weeks.

Comment: @mmyers *and* it surpassed 5 more than a year ago.

Comment: @Randolpho - got one today, too.   Perhaps someone rolled in a bug fix?

Comment: @tvanfosson: good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone just upvoted an old answer of yours (posted at least 3 months ago), bringing it to five votes.  You may be able to spot this answer under your recent activity (the envelope icon in the top bar), but if it was a CW question, you're SOL -- but in that case you can use the data dump to find all of your CW answers, and check each one separately to see if it was upvoted recently (which may show up in the timeline for that question).